# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" won't compile

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

```
11
    at FieldProva.merrTekstin(FieldProva.java:47)
    at FieldProva$2.actionPerformed(FieldProva.java:91)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class FieldProva extends JFrame
{


   /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    char[] alfabeti = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    char[] kodimi =   {'#','@','%','*','^','$','!','&','(',')','-','_','+','[','=',']',';','{','>','}','?',':','<','~','.',','};

    String hyrja;
    char[] hyrjaArray;

    String space = "";
    String fjalet;

    private JPanel paneli = new JPanel();
    private JTextArea hapsira1 = new JTextArea(23, 20);
    private JTextArea hapsira2 = new JTextArea(23, 20);
    private JButton shtyp1 = new JButton("Kodo");
    private JButton pastro = new JButton ("Laje");

    public void merrTekstin()
    {
        hyrja = hapsira1.getText();
        char[] hyrjaArray = hyrja.toCharArray();
        int nrgjatesia = hyrja.length();    
        int[] pozitaEshkronjes = new int[nrgjatesia];    


                for (int i=0; i<=hyrjaArray.length;)
                {
                    if(hyrjaArray[i] == ' ' )
                    {
                        String shkronjamezbrastire = hapsira2.getText();
                        hapsira2.setText(shkronjamezbrastire + "`");
                        i++;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        for(int j=0; j<alfabeti.length; j++)
                            {
                                if(alfabeti[j] == hyrjaArray[i])
                                {    

                                String shkronjat = hapsira2.getText();
                                pozitaEshkronjes[i] = j;
                                String[] nifarRezultati = new String[nrgjatesia];
                                nifarRezultati[i] = Character.toString(kodimi[pozitaEshkronjes[i]]);
                                hapsira2.setText(shkronjat + nifarRezultati[i]);

                                i++;
                                j=0;
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }

    }

    public FieldProva()
    {
        super("Message Encryption | Artan Shala");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(457, 472);
        setVisible(true);
        hapsira1.setBounds(10, 11, 164, 418);
        hapsira1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        hapsira1.setLineWrap(true);


                hapsira1.setBackground(new Color(211, 211, 211));
        pastro.setBounds(186, 197, 63, 23);

        pastro.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {
                hapsira1.setText("");
                hapsira2.setText("");
            }
        });
        shtyp1.setBounds(180, 156, 77, 23);
        shtyp1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
            {
                merrTekstin();
            }
        });
        hapsira2.setBounds(267, 11, 164, 418);
        hapsira2.setLineWrap(true);
        hapsira2.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        hapsira2.setBackground(new Color(211, 211, 211));
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        getContentPane().add(hapsira1);
        getContentPane().add(shtyp1);
        getContentPane().add(pastro);
        getContentPane().add(hapsira2);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new FieldProva();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show the whole first 2-3 lines of your exception message. It has been cut off it seems.

Comment: Also, your code in fact **does** compile just fine, and your problem has nothing to do with non-compiling code. In the future, please present a more complete question.

Answer (score 4):

Your post is missing the most important part, `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, and you haven't indicated the line that causes it:

```
if (alfabeti[j] == hyrjaArray[i]) {
```

Here are the first 3 lines of the exception stacktrace when I run your program:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at foo2.FieldProva.merrTekstin(FieldProva.java:45)
    at foo2.FieldProva$2.actionPerformed(FieldProva.java:84)
```

and again for me the offending line is the one I've shown above.

And the reason is here:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= hyrjaArray.length;) {
```

You should not use `i <= hyrjaArray.length;` but rather should use `i < hyrjaArray.length;`, else you'll gove over the array.